# Comments that only you can see

Tags: version-control, phpstorm, comments, commit

Is there a way in PhpStorm to comment a file but not have those comments pushed up in a commit? Like an annotation of sorts.

I want to make some notes to self, but the rest of the team won't need them to understand what I have done.

Comment: Why would this be a good idea? If the notes are useful to you, then they might be useful to the rest of the team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently possible; you can try a thrid-party [Quick Notes](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4456-quick-notes) plugin  - it allows writing quick memos/notes on the project, like personal comments, todos, etc., that aren't saved into code

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively (and if you don't need long annotations), you can make use of **Bookmarks**:

- Go to the line you want to comment
- Hit `F11` to bookmark it
- Hit `Maj+F11` to show a quick view of bookmarks
- Hit `Ctrl+Enter` to add a description to your newly created bookmark

Later you can hit `Maj+F11` again at any time to list all your notes on the current file.

Not entirely ideal, but kinda does the job.